# WCF Batch Response not formed correctly

Tags: wcf-data-services, odata

I am using WCF Data Service's processing pipeline do some message notification set-up prior to processing the change sets.  I am using batch mode to submit my changes.  I am testing a scenario where the notification service is not running, and therefore we throw a specific message prior to the change set processing.

Here's how my code is set up

```
ProcessingPipeline.ProcessingChangeset += ProcessingChangeset;
```

You can easily mimic my error as follows:

```
private void ProcessingChangeset(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    throw new Exception("Some Specific Messsage");
}
```

When I run my test, I do not get the "Some Specific Message" exception that I expect.  Instead I receive:

> System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceRequestException: An error
>   occurred while processing this request. --->
>   System.InvalidOperationException: Missing change set boundary
>   delimiter. Please make sure that change set boundary delimiter is
>   specified to mark the end of a change set.

I inspected the test response using Fiddler to see the contents.

```
--batchresponse_f158ae30-03c4-479e-8dda-a9129d2a1036
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=changesetresponse_92c24e82-47ad-43a2-b3e2-79d9e5ada261

--batchresponse_f158ae30-03c4-479e-8dda-a9129d2a1036
Content-Type: application/http
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary

HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
DataServiceVersion: 1.0;
Content-Type: application/xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<error xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata">
  <code></code>
  <message xml:lang="en-US">An error occurred while processing this request.</message>
  <innererror>
    <message>Some Specific Message</message>
    <type>System.Exception</type>
    <stacktrace>   at SM.Service.BaseService`1.ProcessingChangeset(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\svn\gr-core\ServiceManager\trunk\SM.Service\BaseService.cs:line 71&#xD;
   at System.Data.Services.DataServiceProcessingPipeline.InvokeProcessingChangeset(Object sender, EventArgs e)&#xD;
   at System.Data.Services.DataService`1.BatchDataService.HandleBatchContent(Stream responseStream)</stacktrace>
  </innererror>
</error>
--changesetresponse_92c24e82-47ad-43a2-b3e2-79d9e5ada261
Content-Type: application/http
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary

HTTP/1.1 204 No Content
Content-ID: 2
Cache-Control: no-cache
DataServiceVersion: 1.0;


--changesetresponse_92c24e82-47ad-43a2-b3e2-79d9e5ada261--
--batchresponse_f158ae30-03c4-479e-8dda-a9129d2a1036--
```

It looks like the duplicate batchresponse entries may be the issue.  Has anyone encountered this or found a work around so the appropriate message can be returned?

Our other functional tests that have errors in the change set processing (not prior) all return the expected messages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This does indeed look like a bug. I checked on our recent builds and the behavior is definitely better (no duplicate boundaries, but a correct error response as far as I can tell).
You could try the latest CTP which might have this fixed here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/astoriateam/archive/2011/10/13/announcing-wcf-data-services-oct-2011-ctp-for-net-4-and-silverlight-4.aspx